# How to compare each element of multiple lists and return name of lists which are different

Tags: python, list

I am having multiple lists and I need to compare each list with one another and return the name of lists which are different. We need to consider value of elements in list irrespective of their position while comparing lists.

For example:-

```
Lis1=['1','2','3']

Lis2=['1','2']

Lis3=['0','1','3']

Lis4=[]

Lis5=['1','2']
```

Output:-

```
['Lis1','Lis2','Lis3','Lis4']
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: By difference, do you consider position also?

Comment: Lewis Hepburn, Position shouldn't we consider only value of elements

Comment: So is `['1', '2']` the same as `['2', '1']`?

Comment: Ok, Please see answer. Thanks.

Comment: Lewis Hepburn, actually in my case I am looking for Cartesian kind of comparison by this method it will be multiple line of code right?

Comment: "return the name of lists which are different" I don't understand; "different" isn't a property of things, it's a property of *pairs of* things. A list can't be "different"; two lists can differ *from each other*.

Comment: Anyway, once you have these names, what exactly do you propose to *do with* them?

Comment: what if you have duplicates: `['1', '1']` and `['1']` what should be the result ? `['1']` or to include both lists?

Comment: kederrac, in my case include both lists

Comment: @kederrac, thanks for pointing this out but in my case where I need to apply this there will not be a case of duplicate entry in list so it worked for me.

Comment: @karl, Actually I am going to use those list for filtering the dataframe.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
input_lists = {"Lis1": ['1', '2', '3'], "Lis2": ['1', '2'],
               "Lis3": ['0', '1', '3'], "Lis4": [], "Lis5": ['1', '2']}

output_lists = {}

for k, v in input_lists.items():
    if sorted(v) not in output_lists.values():
        output_lists[k] = sorted(v)

unique_keys = list(output_lists.keys())
print(unique_keys)  # ['Lis1', 'Lis2', 'Lis3', 'Lis4']
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import itertools

Lis1=['1','2','3']

Lis2=['1','2']

Lis3=['0','1','3']

Lis4=[]

Lis5=['1','2']

k=[Lis1,Lis2,Lis3,Lis4,Lis5]

k.sort()
list(k for k,_ in itertools.groupby(k))
```

output

```
[[], ['0', '1', '3'], ['1', '2'], ['1', '2', '3']]
```

Answer (score 0):

a simple way to implement

```
Lis1=['1','2','3']
Lis2=['1','2']
Lis3=['0','1','3']
Lis4=[]
Lis5=['1','2']

lis=[Lis1,Lis2,Lis3,Lis4,Lis5]
final=[]
for ele in lis:
    if(ele not in final):
        final.append(ele)
print(final)
```

Answer (score 0):

with  your given data you can use:

```
Lis1=['1','2','3']

Lis2=['1','2']

Lis3=['0','1','3']

Lis4=[]

Lis5=['1','2']


name_lis = {'Lis1': Lis1, 'Lis2': Lis2, 'Lis3': Lis3, 'Lis4': Lis4, 'Lis5': Lis5}
tmp = set()
response = []

for k, v in  name_lis.items():
    s = ''.join(sorted(v))
    if s not in tmp:
        tmp.add(s)
        response.append(k)
        
print(response)
```

**output:**

```
['Lis1', 'Lis2', 'Lis3', 'Lis4']
```

`name_lis` dictionary contains the name of your list and the actual list,  you are iterating over each list, and for each list, you are sorting the elements and then converting in a string, if the string was encountered before you  know that the list is a duplicate if not you are adding the list to the response